# How to get SharePoint Online news in PowerApps

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-pages, newsfeed, powerapps-canvas

I want to display news posted to SharePoint Online in PowerApps(Canvas app).
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a flow based on SitePages library, when Promoted state equals 1 or 2, which means news post page, create new item with title and url to list:

[image]

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: For example, When news posted to SPO run PowerAutomate and that information copy to SPO list or Excel etc.. is it possible?

Comment: PowerAutomate is different from Power Apps, Power Automate helps you automate common tasks between SharePoint, PowerApps helps you customize list or library form.Which information in news you want to copy to list?

Comment: I want to get the title and URL of the news.

Comment: I have updated the reply, please check it.In addition, remember to change the issue description to Power automate, this will make your question more accurate.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Now I can display the news link in PowerApps as Gallery.

Comment: Sorry one more question. I can get thumbnail images of news?

Comment: Yes, you could get it with "Thumbnail" property.